# Saving output to two csv columns

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to save the output of my code to two different columns in a csv file.

```
import socket
from sys import argv

script, file1 = argv

list = []

with open(file1) as f:
    for line in f:
        x = socket.gethostbyname(line.strip())
        list.append(x)

with open('returned_hosts.csv', 'w') as r:
    r.write("\n".join(list))
```

Currently the output is the IP's in one column. I'd like to have the 
hostname in one column then the corresponding IP in the next column.

csv output:

```
Column A       Column B
172.217.22.142|Google.com
13.66.212.205 |Bing.com
72.30.35.9    |Yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list of `tuple` to store your output. And use the `csv` module

**Ex:**

```
import csv
import socket
from sys import argv

script, file1 = argv

lst = []

with open(file1) as f:
    for line in f:
        x = socket.gethostbyname(line.strip())
        list.append((x, line))

with open('returned_hosts.csv', 'w', newline='') as r:
    writer = csv.writer(r, delimiter="|")
    writer.writerows(lst)
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, I want IP and host in different columns, not separated by '"|" in the same column.

Comment: @Posteingang. They are actually separate columns..Try `delimiter=","` and open csv in excel

Comment: It works with a comma. Any idea why it skips a line between each write?

Comment: Are you using python3? if so use `newline=''` edited ans

Answer (score 0):

When saving to in .csv format it is best to use [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), which was built for exactly that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following optimized way without holding an external list:

```
import socket
from sys import argv

file1 = argv[1]
with open(file1) as f_in, open('returned_hosts.csv', 'w') as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        h_name = line.strip()
        ip = socket.gethostbyname(h_name)
        f_out.write(f'{ip}|{h_name}\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the `csv` module like,

```
$ cat write.py
import socket
import csv

with open('names.txt') as f, open('hosts.txt', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='|')
    writer.writerow(('ip', 'name'))
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            ip = socket.gethostbyname(line)
            writer.writerow((ip, line))
```

Content of `names.txt`,

```
$ cat names.txt
google.com
twitter.com
```

Then run as,

```
$ python write.py
```

Output:

```
$ cat data.txt
ip|name
172.217.160.142|google.com
104.244.42.193|twitter.com
```